# MySQL value in an HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got something like (In PHP)

```
echo '<input type="email" name="email" value='';
```

What I want is value to be automatically filled out with a value from a MySQL value in a row (Let's call it ['name'], but I seem to running into syntax problems.

What I've tried is something like adding ['name'], '['name']', "['name']", '["name"]', etc to value=, but none of these work. Not sure if I'm just doing this wrong or if this isn't possible. If this sounds too much like 'please fix my code', ignore it please, it's 5 in the morning and I'm strung out. Would gladly enjoy any suggestions or help.

Comment: How do you gather data from MySQL?

Comment: What is "a MySQL form"?

Comment: @Quentin MySQL value, my bad.

Comment: Well, it's a row, but it's pinpointed by something else in the code to only select one value from that row. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Then show us how do you 'pinpoint' it

Comment: @sskoko The data is already in the MySQL row and the value exists, it's just getting it to fill in the email textbox by default with it.

Comment: @sskoko It's just something like $SQL="SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = '$userdefiniedid'";

Comment: How about you show us your full SQL statement? Without it, it is just guess work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print database table field value as Form input value. Just try.

```
echo '<input type="email" name="email" value="'.$row['name'].'"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to make seprate your html code,donot include html inside echo,i am trying to sya that  you can code like

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ['name'] ?>"/>
```

and you will never get any synatx error

Answer (score 0):

```
 I show you the syntax that in HTML
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ['name'] ?>"/>
or 

In main PHP string format if you need.
echo "<input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" value=\"$val\"/>";

Here is $val is filled by you as per requirment.
```